# How to use Protractor with angular-2 form controls?

Tags: angular, protractor

I just started using protractor with angular2. I have written a sample test with protractor below

```
<input type="text"  id="name">


describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
it('should say my name', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:3000/?');
var greeting =element(by.id('name') ).sendKeys('john');
expect(greeting.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('john');
});
});
```

And this worked fine. But i am using forms something like this

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="testControl" />
```

And i dont have any id mentioned on the input control.Is it possible to write tests by using the control name,something like `var greeting=element(by.formcontrol('testControl')).sendKeys('john');`
Because i dont want to mention `Id's or names` for the input.
Can you guys help me out.Correct me if i am wrong.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using css selector for locating the input. have a look at belwo example.

```
element(by.css("input[formControl='testControl']"))
```

Comment: Hi...I got this error " Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, input[formControl="name"])" .

Comment: It doesn't have formControl attribute after the input gets rendered

Answer (score 2):

Also had difficulty with this and getting the accepted answer to work.
I ended up creating a utility method as follows:

```
const input = (name: string) => element(by.css('input[ng-reflect-name=\"' + name + '\"]'));
```

Usage:

```
input('firstName').sendKeys('John');
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because protractor is trying to look for the element before it is visible, right after browser.get(). CSS/XPath selectors usually work, so try this:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
    it('should say my name', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:3000/?');
        var EC= protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('yourElementHere'), 60000);
        var greeting =element(by.id('name') ).sendKeys('john');
        expect(greeting.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('john');
    });
});
```

This will force protractor to wait for the visibility of a particular element (with a timeout) on the page before proceeding further.